# android GridLayout divider row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to implement a tabular layout that has a header and a bunch of rows underneath it. I've chosen the GridLayout (android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout) as there's some requirements for some elements to span multiple columns (but those are of no concern to the question).

My header cells each contain a LinearLayout with a bunch of TextViews, they're dynamically filled in code,for the sake of example, have a look at the image below.
The second row should contain the divider which is a simple view, that should span my header columns (3).

The problem is the width of the divider - if I choose MATCH_PARENT, it will push the GridLayout to fill the whole remaining space to the right. The grid needs to wrap the content and center itself horizontally. It seems to me there's a conflict between the grid's layout (WRAP_CONTENT) and the divider's layout (MATCH_PARENT).

How can I fix the width of the divider without hardcoding it?

http://i61.tinypic.com/2415eg5.png

In red, my LinearLayouts (header), green, the GridLayout itself, the thin blue line at the bottom is the divider.

Thanks,
MO

SOLUTION (as provided below):
I had to set the column weight for the divider to 1, without specifying a width (actually setting it to zero). Because of my specific requirement to handle all of these in code, the solution was to manually instantiate the GridLayout.LayoutParams class and use

```
ColumnSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(row_index, num_spanned_cols, weight)
```

Hope this helps others in the future.

Comment: Somehow i can't figure what you are trying to achieve. Can you post a "MS Paint made" picture of what you are expecting ?

Comment: Hi, have a look here [link](http://1drv.ms/1JLdRzF). If I remove the divider I get the correct layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the width to 0dp then give it             `android:layout_weight="1"`
(you could give it any weight you want) it should fill all the available space and not push your bounds if I understand what you are asking correctly

Comment: Checked it and works in XML, but I couldn't find a way to set it in code. Any ideas ?

Comment: if you call ```.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1)``` where the third paramater, 1, is the weight

Comment: I'm already setting the .setLayoutParams(GridLayout.LayoutParams) that's because I need to specify the column span. Is there a way to also specify the column weight via this type?

Comment: Got it, the solution was ColumnSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(0, 3, 1), with the last parameter being the weight. Thanks a lot!